# AnimationListener inside of a loop? (Wait for animation to complete each time)

Tags: android, animation

UPDATE: To make my question more clear: How should I structure the loop, to ensure that the next iteration doesn't happen until the animation has ended for the previous iteration?

So I'm pretty new to using animations in android. I've got simple animation that runs each time a tile is placed using the `placeTile` method.

The code looks like this:

```
public void setUpPlayers(){

    //Toast for setting turn order
    smallToast(getResources().getString(R.string.deciding_turn_order));

    for (int i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
        if(i == 0){
            players[i] = new Player("HUMAN", 6000);
            players[i].setType(Player.Type.HUMAN);
        } else {
            players[i] = new Player(playerNames[i], 6000);
            players[i].setType(Player.Type.COMPUTER);
        }           
        players[i].drawTile(1);

        TextView nameText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.current_player_text);
        nameText.setText(players[i].getName());

        //find the ID for the tile just placed
        String tileID = players[i].findTileIdByIndex(0);

        placeTile(tileID, i); //Tile ID being placed, and the index of the player placing it
    }
}
```

The issue I have, is I want the loop to NOT execute the next iteration until the animation has completed for the prior tile placed. How can I do this? I know that typically you have to set an AnimationLister and wait for the animation to finish but I'm not sure how to go about doing that since A) the animation is part of the Tile being placed and has a private scope, and B) the loop wants to execute immediately. How can you "Hold" a loop using a Listener?

The one thought that occurred to me would be to re-structure the `setUpPlayers()` method to be a recursive algorithm and each iteration calls the animation, but the reiteration of the method is called inside of the AnimationListener. A recursive algorithm seems like overkill for this though. Any thoughts? What's the best, simplest method to achieve this?

Thanks in advance,

JRad the Bad

Comment: What is your min sdk requirement?

Answer (score -1):

In  my project I have a similar situation and I also set my min sdk to 8 so I used this library to have the same features we have on the latests updates (Animator classes)

Library - http://nineoldandroids.com/

My code:

```
    private class MyAnimationListener implements Animator.AnimatorListener{

                ObjectAnimator spinningAnimation;

                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
                    spinningAnimation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(playerSpinner, "rotationY", degrees); //In my case I just flip a coin
                    spinningAnimation.setDuration(25);
                    spinningAnimation.addListener(new MyAnimationListener());
                }

               @Override    
               public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                   if(repeatCount>0){
                        spinningAnimation.setTarget(playerSpinner);
                        spinningAnimation.start();
                   }
               }

               @Override
               public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {}

               @Override
               public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {}

}
```

If you need some help to understand better, just ask on the comments :)

Comment: I'm familiar with NineOldAndroids but that's not my issue. I can set up custom Event handling if necessary. My issue is that since the animation is inside of a loop, I can't set up an animation event handler and have the loop pause. The loop continues to reiterate regardless of event handling set up inside of it. My question is: How should I structure the loop, to ensure that the next iteration doesn't happen until the animation has ended for the previous iteration.

Comment: @JRadtheBad just calling the start on your end animation doesn't do that? If you set the animation listener to start your sequence at the end of the animation you can just have a boolean or some logic to not call the start... sorry if I didn't understand your question

Comment: The issue is that a lot of other stuff happens inside of that loop. I instantiate the players, set up initial money, and decide names. I can't/shouldn't put all of that inside of an event listener. The number of final and static adjustments I would have to make seems ridiculous. It's not just about having an animation happen back to back, it about not starting the next animation or setting up the next player until the previous animation has finished. A for-loop wants to execute to the end and won't stop by setting a listener. It will keep reiterating.

Comment: Perhaps you've addressed that issue and I'm just not understanding the answer? :/